# How to return a string from a method?

Tags: c#, sql, string, methods

### Question

Why can I not return my variable `SQL` through my method `SQLSelection()`?

I've declared it, then re-assigned it and then returned it. However this doesn't work and along with multiple error messages, nothing is returned?

### Code

```
private void SQLSelection()
{

    String SQL = null;

    if (comboBox1.Text == "All" & comboBox2.Text == "All")
    {
        String SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status FROM dbo.joblist WHERE status in ('New','Hold')";
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "All" & comboBox2.Text == "@status")
    {
        String SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status FROM dbo.joblist WHERE status = @status";
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "@username" & comboBox2.Text == "All")
    {
         String SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status FROM dbo.joblist WHERE status = @username";
    }
    else
    {
        String SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status  FROM dbo.joblist WHERE username = @username and status = @status";
    }

    return String SQL;

}
```

Comment: you are re-declaring your variable inside of if statements.

Comment: "along with multiple error messages" - what are those error messages? Do you understand them? What did you try to do to fix them?

Comment: You have multiple issues here. (1) Declare `SQL` once, at the top. Remove "String" from in front of the rest. (2) Remove the "String" from in front of the return value. (3) Change `void` to String in your function signature.

Comment: I'll bet one of those error messages reads something like "Since "SQLSelection()" returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"......of course `return String SQL;` has problems of its own....

Comment: on slightly unrelated note, you have comboboxes with text values such as @status and @username?  I get the gut feeling that's not what you're really after...

Comment: @user2366842  They are variables is my parametrised sql query that represent what the user has selected in the comboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return type is void, not string.  Change it to:

```
private string SQLSelection()
```

A void is a "returnless" action that is performed upon something and does not "return" back the values of the return statement.  If you try to return a value, you get a compiler error as you are experiencing.

In addition, you keep redeclaring

```
String SQL
```

inside each method.  Simply assign the value to SQL by removing the String declaration in each if statement.

Finally, your return statement is once again trying to redeclare the variable.

Your resulting method should look like:

```
private string SQLSelection()
{
    String SQL = null;

    if (comboBox1.Text == "All" & comboBox2.Text == "All")
    {
        SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status FROM dbo.joblist WHERE status in ('New','Hold')";
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "All" & comboBox2.Text == "@status")
    {
        SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status FROM dbo.joblist WHERE status = @status";
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text == "@username" & comboBox2.Text == "All")
    {
         SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status FROM dbo.joblist WHERE status = @username";
    }
    else
    {
        SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status  FROM dbo.joblist WHERE username = @username and status = @status";
    }

    return SQL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature says returning `void`, which means the method returns nothing.  Change it to:

```
private string SqlSelection()
```

Also you have a few issues with `SqlSelection`, I doubt it even compiles.  Try something like

```
private string SqlSelection()
{
   string sql = null;

   if (comboBox1.Text == "All" & comboBox2.Text == "All")
   {
     sql = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status FROM dbo.joblist WHERE status in ('New','Hold')";
   }
   else if (comboBox1.Text == "All" & comboBox2.Text == "@status")    }

   ...

   return sql;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Your return type should be String instead of void.
    private String SQLSelection() {
2) Don't redaclare your variable in the if statements:
    SQL = "SELECT ..";
3) You don't need the String at the return statement:
    return SQL;

Answer (score 2):

also you can check your varable befor return like this

```
private string SQLSelection()
{
private String SQL = null;

if (comboBox1.Text == "All" & comboBox2.Text == "All")
{
    SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status FROM dbo.joblist WHERE status in ('New','Hold')";
}
else if (comboBox1.Text == "All" & comboBox2.Text == "@status")
{
    SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status FROM dbo.joblist WHERE status = @status";
}
else if (comboBox1.Text == "@username" & comboBox2.Text == "All")
{
     SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status FROM dbo.joblist WHERE status = @username";
}
else
{
    SQL = "SELECT stationID, LocationName, plandate, username, status  FROM dbo.joblist WHERE username = @username and status = @status";
}
if(SQL != null)
    return SQL;
else 
   return "any phrase you want ";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains at least these errors:

1. The return type of your method is declared `void` (meaning it does not have any return value), so you cannot return anything from it. Change the return type to `string`:

   ```
   private string SQLSelection()
   ```
2. You are attempting to redeclare the `SQL` variable where you are assigning to it, and in the return statement. For example, instead of:

   ```
           String SQL = "…";
   ```

   it should be just:

   ```
           SQL = "…";
   ```

   and instead of:

   ```
       return String SQL;
   ```

   it should be just:

   ```
       return SQL;
   ```

   (`String SQL;` is the syntax for declaring a variable `SQL` of type `string`. You are declaring the variable right at the beginning of your method; you don't need to redeclare it later on.)